# Elements from different themes wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, elementor

I'm new to wordpress and i have  a simple question. I've been developing shopify for a long time and i find it really easy to use comparing to wordpress. (Or im just new who knows) The fact that i can't customize a theme html&css directly and i have to go through php to do that is frustrating me.

I bought 2 themes built on Elementor. And i want to use elements from the first theme in the second theme..
Like, i have a cool element with a slideshow that i want to use in my current template...
Is that possible on wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

you can export template from edit with elementor page option from first theme and use in second theme with import template option available in elementor edit page.

Comment: Anything that can be in the comment section should be. Answer should be developed. This does not provide an answer to the question`, to maximise your chance of getting your answer **[accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** and **[upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)**, please **[Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and read **[How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**.